# Inconsistency of xcolor and sgamex packages

Tags: color

I have a wired problem with `xcolor` package, I think the problem is about package `sgamex`, but I can't solve it.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{adjustbox}
\usepackage{amssymb,amsmath,amsthm}
\usepackage{bm}
\usepackage{colortbl}
\usepackage{commath}
\usepackage{datetime}
\usepackage{dirtytalk}
\usepackage{etoolbox,refcount}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[font=scriptsize,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{istgame}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{multicol}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage[pdfusetitle, hidelinks, pdfencoding=auto, colorlinks=true, linkcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{pgfplots}\pgfplotsset{compat=1.13}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\usepackage{sgamex}
\usepackage[shell]{gnuplottex}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tikz, tkz-euclide, siunitx, tkz-tab}
\usepackage{tkz-euclide}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{verbatim}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{xcolor}
```

I got this error:

```
! LaTeX Error: Option clash for package xcolor.
```

Answer (score 1):

After I read the [manual](https://www.economics.utoronto.ca/osborne/latex/sgamex.pdf) in page 2 of the `sgamex` package I found this:

> To use the package in a document, put the line `\usepackage{sgamex}`
> in the preamble. It loads the `xcolor` package with the option table,
> so if your document loads another package that loads `xcolor` without
> an option, you need to load `sgamex` first or to load `xcolor` early with
> the table option.

So I move the `\usepackage{sgamex}` to the first.

Comment: you could simply remove \usepackage{xcolor} as your other package already loads it.

Comment: note that you are separately loading xcolor and colortbl so even without sgamex that is wrong and you should use `\usepackage[table]{xcolor}` or in this case deleet both packages as sgamex is doing this for you. (unrelated but I would not use `commath` it isn't really usable)